# CSS and JavaScript function to toogle p text in boxes without expanding other boxes?

Tags: javascript, css

I am manage to toogle the p text from individual boxes but the box in the same section still does expand, even if the text is not shown. How could I avoid the other box to expand?

I tried the function getElementbyID and getElementByClassName but none of them work either. I am not sure if it is an issue wit JS or with the CSS property.

Thank you!

````
 <section class="collapse">
        <div class="motherboxes">
          <h3>
          Title #1
          </h3>
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab dolorum voluptas, rerum aliquam totam eaque ratione cumque voluptate similique! Repudiandae adipisci, tenetur qui! Quibusdam rem unde ipsam molestias repellat ut.
          </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="motherboxes">
          <h3>Title #2</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
          </p>
        </div>
        </section>
        <section class="collapse">
        <div class="motherboxes">
          <h3>
          Title #3
          </h3>
          <p>
          Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab dolorum voluptas, rerum aliquam totam eaque ratione cumque voluptate similique! Repudiandae adipisci, tenetur qui! Quibusdam rem unde ipsam molestias repellat ut.
          </p>
        </div>
        
        <div class="motherboxes">
          <h3>Title #4</h3>
          <p>
            Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. 
          </p>
        </div>
        </section>

```

.collapse {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction:row;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
  }
  
  .motherboxes {
    align-items: row;
    border: none;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background: #fff3f3;
    margin: 0.5em;
    padding: 1em;
    flex-basis:45%;
    cursor: pointer;
  }
  
  .motherboxes h3 {
    text-align: center;
  }
  
  .motherboxes p {
  display: none;
  }
  
  .motherboxes.active p {
    display: block;
  }
  
  .motherboxes:hover{
      box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  } 

```

const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".motherboxes");

elements.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
    el.classList.toggle('active');
}))
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Only you have to make different `sections` for all boxes so that it expands separately by using JS.

```js
const elements = document.querySelectorAll(".motherboxes");

elements.forEach((el) => el.addEventListener('click', () => {
  el.classList.toggle('active');
}))
```

```css
.collapse {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.motherboxes {
  align-items: row;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 10px;
  background: #fff3f3;
  margin: 0.5em;
  padding: 1em;
  flex-basis: 45%;
  cursor: pointer;
}

.motherboxes h3 {
  text-align: center;
}

.motherboxes p {
  display: none;
}

.motherboxes.active p {
  display: block;
}

.motherboxes:hover {
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<section class="collapse">
  <div class="motherboxes">
    <h3>
      Title #1
    </h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab dolorum voluptas, rerum aliquam totam eaque ratione cumque voluptate similique! Repudiandae adipisci, tenetur qui! Quibusdam rem unde ipsam molestias repellat ut.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="collapse">
  <div class="motherboxes">
    <h3>Title #2</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="collapse">
  <div class="motherboxes">
    <h3>
      Title #3
    </h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Ab dolorum voluptas, rerum aliquam totam eaque ratione cumque voluptate similique! Repudiandae adipisci, tenetur qui! Quibusdam rem unde ipsam molestias repellat ut.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>

<section class="collapse">
  <div class="motherboxes">
    <h3>Title #4</h3>
    <p>
      Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.
    </p>
  </div>
</section>
```

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi! Yes, it solved the issue. Thank you very much. I had include the flex property so that they wouldn't stack as a column, but it worked great! Thanx!

Comment: Your Welcome, I am so glad it helps you!